# For Each Loop append div

Tags: jquery, json, html, append

I'm trying to load products from *json* file using for loop. For every product I want to have a div (every item in a div). I have no problem with loading but somehow the first item data, looks like its being concatenate with the next item. I tried to go through net solutions and the closest I got is something to do with parent. (I'm still green at jQuery). The amount of divs for each item is working correctly.

```
if($.isArray(item.product_Shorts)){
    $.each(item.product_Shorts, function(i, item){
        $('#CasualItems').append("<div class='title'>");
        $('.title').append(item.product_ID);
    });
}
```

Currently I have two products, one with id 3 and another with 4. (for the sake of this I'm displaying ID instead of Title. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, you don't actually ask a question in your post... I think we're both assuming your question....

Comment: @Dav, I think Jesse has the answer. As you refer to  your layer as $(".title"), the product_id (or whatever) is added to every layer with the class "title".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if($.isArray(item.product_Shorts)){
    $.each(item.product_Shorts, function(i, item){
        $('#CasualItems').append("<div class='title'>").html(item.product_ID);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think I did not explained properly. I need the div of the second item (the second loop) does not affect the first previous data in div of first item.
The result I want should look like this: 
<div class="title"> 3</div>
<div class="title"> 4</div>

Comment: @dav At least you could have given +1, this solution is more elegant thant the one you marked as answer.

Comment: I guess I can only do +1 to one question, and will.i.am reply with a working solution before.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, it appends the div and appends the product ID of 3 (to all 'title' classes). In the second pass, it appends a div and then adds the product ID of 4 (again to all 'title' classes, of which there are now 2).

Just do this instead:

```
$('#CasualItems').append("<div class='title'>").append(item.product_ID);
```

Comment: @Pete I want to improve the quality of the answers posted here and if I raise reputation too, it's Ok.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are adding it to every `.title div`. try doing it by `id` or index.

```
$('.title').eq(i).append(item.product_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using unique `id` for each `div`

```
if($.isArray(item.product_Shorts)){
    $.each(item.product_Shorts, function(i, item){
        $('#CasualItems').append("<div id='title'" + (i + 1) + ">");
        $('#title' + (i + 1)).append(item.product_ID);
    });
}
```